# How to add a listener to an MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, events, uitextfield

I am trying to send an SMS on an iPhone using MFMessageComposeVieController and I want to add a listener that recognizes when the SMS is sent (in other words, when the user presses "Send"). What is the syntax for this?

For example, I know that with a textField, an example of a listener would be: 
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(methodName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

Comment: Is this all contained within the same class? Or do you wish to detect when a message is sent in a different class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a delegate to your `MFMessageComposeViewController`.  In the delegate's `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` method, you can check the result parameter to see whether the user canceled or sent the SMS.

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller 
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
        switch(result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            // user canceled sms
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            // user sent sms
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            // sms send failed
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to do it without using a delegate?

Comment: No you need to implement the delegate. That is what it is for. You could use the delegate to fire a Notification if you require elsewhere to find out about the SMS being sent.

Answer (score 1):

[Google is very helpful...](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=MFMessageComposeViewController)

Third result is [an SMS tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/).

Relevant code:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"MyApp" 
                                message:@"Unknown Error"
                               delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@”OK” 
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Implement the `MessageComposeResultSent` case to know when the message has been sent.